# Reading file per bytes

Tags: c++, fstream

I have a simple program:

```
#include <cstring>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    cout << "Creating test.txt file..." << endl;

    // Writing to file
    fstream fWrite;
    fWrite.open("./_test_data/test.txt", fstream::out | fstream::trunc);
    if (fWrite.fail()) {
        cout << "Creating test.txt file failed!" << endl;
        fWrite.close();
    } else {
        fWrite << (char) 0x09 << (char) 0x0A << (char) 0x0B;
        fWrite << (char) 0x0C << (char) 0x0D << (char) 0x0E;
        fWrite << flush;

        fWrite.close();
        cout << "test.txt file successfully created." << endl;
    }

    // Reading created file
    cout << "Reading test.txt file..." << endl;
    fstream fRead;
    fRead.open("./_test_data/test.txt", fstream::in);
    if (fRead.fail()) {
        fRead.close();
    } else {
        char character;

        while (true) {
            fRead >> character;

            if (fRead.eof()) {
                cout << (int)character << endl;
                cout << "EOF detected!" << endl;
                break;
            }

            cout << (int)character << endl;
        }
        fRead.close();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

It should just write bytes in order `09 0A 0B 0C 0D 0E`, which is done ok (checked by hexdump), but when reading the same file, it reads first byte as `0E` (= 14 in decimal) and then comes EOF...

```
Creating test.txt file...
test.txt file successfully created.
Reading test.txt file...
14
14
EOF detected!
```

Why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `fRead.read(&character,1)` instead of `fRead >> character`.

But you can also delete the `cout << (int)character << endl;` in the if statement.

Answer (score 1):

Open the file in binary mode: `fRead.open("...", fstream::in | fstream::binary);` - this is to keep the file layer from translating newline sequences.

Comment: This answer is necessary, but not sufficient. In addition to opening in binary mode, the OP must either use noskipws or avoid the extraction operator.

Answer (score 0):

Try `fRead >> std::noskipws`. The `>>` operator on read streams skips whitespaces to get to the next 'interesting' data.  Consider an input stream like `hi there`.  Reading that a `std::string` at a time, you'd get `hi` and `there`, with the space character ignored. Simiarly, reading that a character at a time, you get -h-i-t-h-e-r-e-, with the space character ignored.

The bytes that you couldn't read from fRead were all considered white space, so they were all ignored.

The reason that `fRead.read()` is a solution (and a good one) is that it does unformatted input -- it doesn't care about whitespace.

Finally, you should make these other changes to your program:

```
#include <iostream>  // you need this for std::cout and std::endl
```

You need `iostream` for `std::cout` and `std::endl`.

fRead.open("./_test_data/test.txt", fstream::in | fstream::binary);

You need to open the test file in binary (both for writing and reading) if you are going to have any non-printable characters in it.